# "error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory" - Python Dedupe Installtion

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dedupe

I am trying to install `dedupe` [module](https://pypi.org/project/dedupe/) and I am getting an error below,

> error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

---

> Failed building wheel for dedupe
>       Failed building wheel for dedupe-hcluster
>       Failed building wheel for affinegap
>       Failed building wheel for pylbfgs
>       Failed building wheel for pyhacrf-datamade

I found this [link](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/issues/407), that did not help me to resolve.

I am using Windows 10 , 64-bit, Python 3.5.4 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit).

I found the `.whl` file [here](https://pypi.org/project/dedupe/#files), (dedupe-1.9.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl) downloaded it and tried to use `pip install <>.whl` and I got an error,

> dedupe-1.9.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel
>   on this platform.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally, after more research I successfully installed `dedupe` library. Just thought of posting my own answer if anyone might come across this issue.

In the beginning I only had `Visual Studio Build Tools 2017` installed with `Visual Studio 2015`.

After posting the question I installed `Visual Studio Community 2017 (2)`. And then tried use `pip install dedupe` still gave me errors like in this [post](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4011).

Then according to the post, I upgraded the `numpy =1.14` and tried `pip install dedupe`, it worked.

(I am not an expert python setup person, not sure how to explain other than this plain explanation)

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my python version and it worked first try